# Cant get a music file to play

Tags: android, file, audio

I am trying to let the user choose a file and then play it later.

```
case R.id.choose_ringtone_btn:
        isPaused = true;
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Audio "), REQUEST_ID);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        savefile(uri);
        editor.putString(URI_STR, uri.toString()).commit();
    }
}

void savefile(Uri sourceuri)
{
    String sourceFilename= sourceuri.getPath();
    String destinationFilename = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separatorChar+"abc.mp3";

    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;

    try {
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
      bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationFilename, false));
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      bis.read(buf);
      do {
        bos.write(buf);
      } while(bis.read(buf) != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
      try {
        if (bis != null) bis.close();
        if (bos != null) bos.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {

      }
    }
}
```

I cant get pass this: bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceFilename));
Why is that?

Comment: What is it doing? An error? Describe the problem?

Comment: Yes, an error. it jump to the "catch"...

Comment: You know, the error message would be a nice addition to the post.

Comment: Without a stack trace and any other context, there's a variety of things that can be going wrong. Source file missing? Source file not readable? No access to the file system? Some very basic debugging would help here.

Comment: Hey, I think I know you in real life. Is that you, Ro-i?

Comment: I dont think you know me paul...  and the error is runtime exeption.